# Create multiple bitmap image from canvas and print that by using DrawingVisual in wpf C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create multiple bitmap image from canvas by doing some alteration and store them into drawing visual control.After that it will go for print in a thermal printer.

Here my Code.

```
public void ConvertCanvasToBitmap_second(Canvas surface)
        {
            PrintingLabelAreaCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            RenderTargetBitmap[] renderTargetBitmaps = new RenderTargetBitmap[2];
            Label lblPagination = new Label
            {
                Name = "lblPagination",
                FontSize = 6
            };
            surface.Children.Add(lblPagination);
            Canvas.SetRight(lblPagination, 0);
            Canvas.SetBottom(lblPagination, 0);
            // Get the size of canvas
            System.Windows.Size size = new System.Windows.Size(surface.Width, surface.Height);
            // Measure and arrange the surface
            // VERY IMPORTANT
            surface.Measure(size);
            surface.Arrange(new Rect(size));
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                lblPagination.Content = (i + 1).ToString();
                // Create a render bitmap and push the surface to it
                RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =
                  new RenderTargetBitmap(
                    (int)size.Width,
                    (int)size.Height,
                    96d,
                    96d,
                    PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
                renderBitmap.Render(surface);
                renderTargetBitmaps[i] = renderBitmap;
            }
            var vis = new DrawingVisual();
            using (var dc = vis.RenderOpen())
            {
                for(int i = 0; i<renderTargetBitmaps.Length; i++)
                {
                    dc.DrawImage(renderTargetBitmaps[i], new Rect(0, 0, (int)size.Width, (int)size.Height));
                }

                PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
                printDlg.PrintVisual(vis, "Label Printing.");
            }
        }
```

When I'm sending it to print, there is nothing print. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if it helps:

```
 public void ConvertCanvasToBitmap_second(Canvas surface)
    {
        //mycanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        RenderTargetBitmap [] renderTargetBitmaps = new RenderTargetBitmap [2];
        Label lblPagination = new Label
        {
            Name = "lblPagination",
            FontSize = 6
        };
        surface.Children.Add(lblPagination);
        Canvas.SetRight(lblPagination, 0);
        Canvas.SetBottom(lblPagination, 0);
        // Get the size of canvas
        System.Windows.Size size = new System.Windows.Size(surface.Width, surface.Height);
        // Measure and arrange the surface
        // VERY IMPORTANT
        surface.Measure(size);
        surface.Arrange(new Rect(size));
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            lblPagination.Content = (i + 1).ToString();
            // Create a render bitmap and push the surface to it
            RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =
              new RenderTargetBitmap(
                (int)size.Width,
                (int)size.Height,
                96d,
                96d,
                PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            renderBitmap.Render(surface);

            renderTargetBitmaps[i] = renderBitmap;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < renderTargetBitmaps.Length; i++)
        {
            var vis = new DrawingVisual();
            using (var dc = vis.RenderOpen())
            {
                dc.DrawImage(renderTargetBitmaps[i], new Rect(0, 0, (int)size.Width, (int)size.Height));
            }

            PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
            printDlg.PrintVisual(vis, "Label Printing.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for help but Drawing visuals couldn't draw any image!!

Comment: Hi @Trident please check it now.

Comment: yes it's working thanks bro.. but I added one label with name of lblPagination that is not appear on paper after print.

Comment: @Trident add the following after you set the label content. Action emptyDelegate = delegate { };
                surface.Dispatcher.Invoke(emptyDelegate, DispatcherPriority.Render);

Comment: Sorry it's not working, but if i assign content with value at the time of initialization, then its work but not update the value through loop.

Comment: @Trident did you add it after you set the label content?

Comment: Is there any way to enhance the image quality?? coz barcode is not appear very well to read by barcode scanner.